# Parachains not producing blocks with polkadot release-v1.4.0

Tags: polkadot, zombienet

I am running a local zombienent network with zombienet version `1.3.86`

The `config.toml` file:

```
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
chain = "westend-local"
default_command = "./polkadot"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  ws_port = 9900
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
cumulus_based = true
chain = "asset-hub-westend-local"

  [[parachains.collators]]
  name = "charlie"
  validator = true
  command = "./bin/polkadot-parachain"
  ws_port = 9910
  args = ["--force-authoring"]
```

The relay chain is producing blocks, however, the parachain doesn't.

[image]

There seem to be no errors by looking at the zombienet log files.

Comment: Hi @Szegoo,  thanks for reporting. I can't reproduce with `polkadot 1.4.0-a3e4fce9d3f` and the latest version of zombienet. Which version os zombienet are you using and which provider? Thx!!

Comment: I had an older version of zombienet . After updating to the latest release I no longer have this issue. However, the parachain, even though registered on the relay chain doesn't produce blocks. This is only happening on `release-1.4.0`.

Comment: Hi @Szegoo, let me try to reproduce and check the block production. Thx!

Comment: @Szegoo am getting same errors using latest polkadot binaries as no blocks are being produced for parachains

Comment: Hi @Szegoo / @mrisho-lukamba,  looks like your polkadot binary wasn't compile with `fast-runtime` and the epoch is 1hr (you need to wait 2 epoch before the parachain start producing blocks). I tested locally with fast-runtime and works as expected. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I mention in my [comment](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10631/parachains-not-producing-blocks-with-polkadot-release-v1-4-0#comment10525_10631) using the latest version of [zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/releases/tag/v1.3.86) will work with that config *but* you need to compile `polkadot` with `fast-runtime` to reduce the epoch time (`parachains` start to producing blocks after 2 epochs).

You can compile `polkadot` with `fast-runtime` with this command

```sh
cargo build --locked --profile testnet --features fast-runtime --bin polkadot --bin polkadot-prepare-worker --bin polkadot-execute-worker
```

Thanks!